# Elasticsearch best mapping for performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, mapping

This is my first time using Elasticsearch and I have my tests working even with nested objects and parent-child relationship. However, I'm a bit stuck on which method to take keeping performance in mind.

So what I need searching is a support ticket system and need tickets and their replies indexed. However, there is other data that I need indexed with it. So say a ticket has multiple different meta data attached to it like what kind of food the ticket is about (different meats, different fruits, etc). So say I want to find all tickets that has to do with apples regardless what kind of specific apple (fuzzy search). So I could have this parent-child relationship in my mapping:

```
{
    mapping : {
        ticket : {},
        food : {
            _parent : {
                type : 'ticket'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I could do a nested object or I could just have a field like "foodName" and "foodId".

So my question is which strategy should I use? My database has a few hundred thousand tickets, over a million replies, over 500,000 users so I need to keep performance in mind with my mapping but I don't have enough experience to make a long term decision on which strategy especially knowing that parent/child relationships cannot be added down the road.

More info is I will also have different search indices where I will be returning facets so I really do feel like I need to set things up with performance in mind. And this is using AWS' Elasticsearch service.

Here are some sample datas that I've created. For the support ticket system, something like this:

```
{
    "tid"              : 1234,
    "uid"              : 1111,
    "sid"              : "111-22222",
    "open_date"        : "2012-06-30 21:38:11",
    "close_date"       : null,
    "status"           : "Open",
    "title"            : "Food Help",
    "raw_text"         : "I need some help!",
    "owner"            : 999,
    "reply_count"      : 1,
    "reason_id"        : 4,
    "food_id"          : 345,
    "food_info"        : {
        "id"   : 345,
        "name" : "Fuji Apple"
    },
    "opener_info"      : {
        "uid"   : 1111,
        "name"  : "Bob Smith",
        "email" : "bob@smith.com"
    },
    "owner_info"       : {
        "uid"   : 999,
        "name"  : "Joe Smith",
        "email" : "joe@smith.com"
    },
    "reason_info"      : {
        "id"     : 4,
        "reason" : "Help"
    },
    "replies"          : [
        {
            "rid"        : 2222,
            "tid"        : 1234,
            "uid"        : 999,
            "reply_date" : "2014-07-30 14:07:21",
            "raw_body"   : "What do you need help with?"
        }
    ],
    "subscription"     : {
        "sid"     : "111-22222",
        "company" : "Bob Smith Company"
    }
}
```

I also have a forum so I have forum/threads/posts for another facet. Here is sample data for it:

```
{
    "threadid"     : 202,
    "title"        : "test",
    "firstpostid"  : 298,
    "lastpostid"   : 300,
    "lastpost"     : 1471546381,
    "lastposterid" : 200,
    "lastposter"   : "test-user",
    "forumid"      : 101,
    "open"         : 1,
    "replycount"   : 2,
    "postusername" : "test-user",
    "postuserid"   : 200,
    "dateline"     : 1471540483,
    "visible"      : 1,
    "sticky"       : 0,
    "taglist"      : null,
    "keywords"     : "test",
    "posts"        : [
        {
            "postid"      : 298,
            "threadid"    : 202,
            "username"    : "test-user",
            "userid"      : 200,
            "title"       : "test",
            "dateline"    : 1471540483,
            "pagetext"    : "test",
            "visible"     : 1,
            "vote_rating" : 0
        },
        {
            "postid"      : 299,
            "threadid"    : 202,
            "username"    : "test-user",
            "userid"      : 200,
            "title"       : "",
            "dateline"    : 1471541280,
            "pagetext"    : "test",
            "visible"     : 1,
            "vote_rating" : 0
        },
        {
            "postid"      : 300,
            "threadid"    : 202,
            "username"    : "test-user",
            "userid"      : 200,
            "title"       : "",
            "dateline"    : 1471546381,
            "pagetext"    : "Whoa, that was weird!",
            "visible"     : 1,
            "vote_rating" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The object and arrays come from joins and other queries. Each array can have any number and can be hundreds potentially thousands of entries and each text for a reply or post can be very long (LONGTEXT in MySQL).

Also, someone asked me what kind of searching if it will be advanced filtering or just quick searching. Of course quick searching will be used (along with suggestions) but there will be many times where there will be date ranges, number ranges and of course fulltext searching. I'll need to search a the child (a reply of a ticket) but retrieve the parent document.

Comment: That's a more complicated subject and it involves the types of queries you want to run, how does the data look like (how many fields, how large they are), how often you update the documents, which documents get changed and which not, **how many children a parent can have**, how often you run certain queries, how does the cluster look like, how many nodes, what's the memory size, how many cpu cores, the storage is SSD or HDD etc.

Comment: If you could answer some of the questions in my previous reply, I can try and evaluate which one **might** be better and establish some testing scenarios (always test your ideas as best as possible before going into production).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. For the ticket system, replies don't get modified that often but another facet I plan to add will. A ticket can have lots of replies, currently largest has 158 replies but can of course be more and a single reply can be very long (LONGTEXT in MySQL). A reply will only have the text and a title but a ticket will have multiple meta like what product, who opened the ticket, who the ticket is assigned to, etc.

Comment: I currently am using free tier of AWS Elasticsearch service so the cluster is not built out but I do plan on the search being used frequently so I need to handle tens if not hundreds of thousands of queries a day but will be using AWS' hosted service.

Comment: I've also edited my top reply with some simple test datas.